# Chi as a weapon?

Tags: technique, tai-chi

For martial artists that focus on chi manipulation, how do you use chi as a weapon? Do you inject your chi to disrupt the opponent's chi flow, do you make it blast to increase the power of your blows?

I am sorry. I am practicing a purely physical martial arts and I only know that chi is present in every living things, so I am asking this to know more.

Also, is a chi blast really possible? Can it really be used as a weapon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're being serious than here goes.  Chi is more of a metaphysical thing.  It doesn't exist in the way that you are thinking.  There are definitely basis' for what you're getting at with the flow of energy, but that is more about the movement and structure of the body than any form of energy.  No you can't form a chi blast, you will just end up looking dumb trying.  That said, "chi strikes" are effective for the same reason that acupuncture is effective.  If you hit the right nerve in the right place at the right time it hurts a lot (think hitting your elbow/funny bone).  This is however, not practical in any real situation. That is not to say that tai chi is not an effective art, just that the application you are aiming this question at is unrealistic and you've probably been watching too much anime.

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanation. I am indeed serious in asking these because I admit my ignorance in this matter. Thank you for taking me seriously too.

Answer (score 4):

No. There is no evidence that chi does anything, let alone going as far as creating an actual weapon.